# how can I get a reference to current Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action or decendant

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I need a reference to the "current" running action from the code of a block.

i.e. I have a $this which is a descendant of Mage_Core_Block_Template and I need a way to call methods on the an instance of Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action for the current request.

I hope this was clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that I can use $this->getAction()

Answer (score 4):

Couple of things come to mind:

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()
```

Also every block since all of them extends the Mage_Core_Block_Abstract have the following method:

```
$this->getRequest()
```

This return a Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http which contains various methods like getControllerModule() or getModuleName().

HTH

Comment: In particular: Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction() will give you the current instance of Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action.

Comment: @drj201 this should be an answer instead of a comment