# Get URL key of Magento page?

Tags: url, magento, content-management-system, key

I'd like to retrieve the URL key of any Magento page so I can include it in a conditional statement in my '1column.phtml' template.

How do I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways:
[how can I get a reference to current Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action or decendant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5002602/471559)